# How do I import from xlsx file via Openpyxl into a Python Class?

Tags: python, class, openpyxl

I have an xlsx file which opens with Openpyxl. Each row contains student_id, first_name, second_name, parent_name and parent_email.

I have created a method called Students

I want the program to take each row and assign it to the method eg.

```
Students(student_id = ['A -row number'], first_name = ['B -row number'], second_name = ['C - row number] ...etc
```

so that it cycles through all of my students and automatically adds them

pretty sure the answer lies in a loop such as:

```
for row in ws.rows:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way was much better. Ditch Openpyxl, open it from a csv file.
In the csv file I have rows each individual bit of information in columns A,B,C,D,E

eg. A1 = Potter, Harry  B1 = Potter C1 = Harry... etc

```
import csv


#sorts all the student data into a class
class Students():
    def __init__(self,student_id, first_name,second_name,student_parent,parent_email):

        self.student_id = student_id
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.second_name = second_name
        self.student_parent = student_parent
        self.parent_email = parent_email


    def __repr__(self):
        return self.student_id + " " + self.first_name + " " +self.second_name + " " + self.student_parent + " " + self.parent_email


student_list = []

#opens the csv file, takes out the information and saves them in the Student Class
student_file = open('student_list.csv')
student_file_reader = csv.reader(student_file)
for row in student_file:
    row_string = str(row)
    row_parts1,row_parts2,row_parts3,row_parts4,row_parts5 = row_string.split(',')
    student_list.append(Students(row_parts1,row_parts2,row_parts3,row_parts4,row_parts5))
```

...and there you have it, all in formation in objects within a list perfect.

Comment: I have asked 4 questions recently to Stack Overflow and have increasingly found the community to be more snarky. 3 out of 4 of my questions I have answered myself and hopefully will help others. People of SO please help newbies, if you have the need to downvote say why you have otherwise that's as helpful as tutting. Also if you're going to just be critical of the question rather than offer help you're distracting from the topic...its like someone asking you for the time and you replying that watches are available in shops.